# The subplot function called in different matlab views

Tags: matlab

I have built a matlab application consisting of 2 views, each one knowing about the other's handle. 
The main view launches the second view and gets its handle.

Then the function `subplot()` is called in the main view and an image is displayed using `imshow()`. 
What I would like to do is to display in the second view several details of the image, also by using the `subplot()` and `imshow()` functions.

Using the handle of the second view I call from the main view a function defined in the second view, which further calls subplot() and `imshow()` functions for details.

What happens is that initial image in the main view disappears being replaced with the details. 
Can anybody give me an advice so that I can have the image displayed in the main view while the details are shown in the second view ?

Comment: Post a short bit of code that demonstrates the problem; it is easier to help when we have code to work with.

Comment: You can use two new lines to denote paragraphs in your posts, rather than a single new line which is ignored. Also, please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures). You can also denote inline code with `\`backticks\``.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify the axis in which you are placing your image or data.  The `imshow` command allows you specify the axes to use for displaying images with the `Parent` parameter.

Combine this with the fact that `subplot` returns a handle to the axis it creates and you have.

```
h = subplot(m,n,i) %# create a subplot axes
imshow(img,'Parent',h) %# display an image in the previously created axis
```

Assuming you can pass information between the two sets of code you would need to retrieve the handle to the axis you want the image to show up in and use that handle in the call to `imshow`. Here is an example

```
hFig = figure;
h(1) = subplot(2,2,1)
h(2) = subplot(2,2,2)
setappdata(hFig,'axisHandles',h) %# stores the axes handles in appdata of the figure
....
```

Now when you want to show some an image in the first figure you can do the following assuming you know the handle to each of your figure windows.

```
h=getappdata(hFig,'axisHandles')
imshow(img,'Parent',h(1))
```

Comment: I bet this is close to right... but the problem may be one level up: the call to `subplot` will work with the current figure, which is why the "main window" plots are getting replaced. The appropriate figure can be made current with `figure(fig_handle)` before calling `subplot`.

Comment: @tmpearce Thanks for the comment.  I have added clarifications that might clear up how the OP can use the parent parameter in `imshow` to specify which axes to display the image.